# Terraform Define FortiOS VIP Group Member block from child module outputs

Tags: terraform, fortigate

I am using Terraform to build Fortigate resources within a custom child module I've defined.  Each instance of the child module will build 12 unique VIPs using the [fortios_firewall_vip](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/fortinetdev/fortios/latest/docs/resources/fortios_firewall_vip) resource.
Inside the root module, I'm attempting to define a VIP Group using the [fortios_firewall_vipgrp](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/fortinetdev/fortios/latest/docs/resources/fortios_firewall_vipgrp) resource, which would include **ALL** of the VIPs built from **ALL** instances of the child module.  I seem to be struggling with how to build the member{} block within the vipgrp resource.

Here is a breakdown of the folder structure:

```
root/
| _
    fortinet.tf
    modules/instance
    | _
        main.tf
        outputs.tf
```

The *main.tf* file is where I'm building the 12 unique VIPs for **each** instance, and the *outputs.tf* file is where I'm saving all of the VIP names to reference in the *fortinet.tf* root file.
I've tried to save the VIP names as a list and as a map, but I'm not sure which is the better approach.

Example of list output:

```
output "vips" {
  value = [
    fortios_firewall_vip.vip1.name,
    fortios_firewall_vip.vip2.name,
    etc...
  ]
}
```

Example of map output:

```
output "vips" {
  value = {
    name = fortios_firewall_vip.vip1.name
    name = fortios_firewall_vip.vip2.name
    etc...
  }
}
```

In the root fortinet.tf file, I'm defining a single VIP Group with the member block and trying to "splat" all instances VIPs in there.
I thought perhaps with the map outputs, I could simply merge them all into one giant block like so:

```
resource "fortios_firewall_vipgrp" "vipgrp" {
  name = "example-vipgrp"
  member = merge(module.instance[*].vips)
}
```

However, I'm receiving an error saying
`An argument named "member" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "member"?`

I'm a newb with Terraform, so I'm struggling with what terminology I should be Googling for assistance here...  Is this even possible?

Any input would be extremely helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[member](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/fortinetdev/fortios/latest/docs/resources/fortios_firewall_vipgrp#member) is a **block**, not argument. So it should be:

```
resource "fortios_firewall_vipgrp" "vipgrp" {
  name = "example-vipgrp"
  member {
     # this merge here probably also need changing, 
     # but my answer covers your error of missing member block, 
     # not whether your merge is correct or not.
     name = merge(module.instance[*].vips)
 }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback on this!
It turns out that what I am trying to accomplish can't even be done with the Terraform FortiOS provider, but is still possible on the Fortigate.
When attempting to add several VIPs in a row to the member{} block, it complains about a character limit in the range of 0 - 64, which seems a bit ridiculous to me.